# building entity data source control from code behind

Tags: entitydatasource

if i have an entitydatasource control in my aspx (which looks like so
and was created by the configure wizard in the designer and works)

```
<asp:EntityDataSource ID="edsFuelPrices" runat="server"
                        ConnectionString="name=enerEntities" DefaultContainerName="enerEntities"
                        EnableFlattening="False" EntitySetName="dieselprices" Select="it.[date], it.[NYMarineDiesel]">
                </asp:EntityDataSource>
```

I want to build that in the code behind and remove all the attributes from the aspx markup.
Why doesnt the following work? I get errors on the load "The query syntax is not valid. Near escaped identifier '[NYMarineDiesel]', line 1, column 21" even though NYMarineDiesel is a valid column in the table

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
        ' when page loads for the first time just show the Marine diesel prices
        Try
            edsFuelPrices.ConnectionString = "name=enerteckEntities"
            edsFuelPrices.DefaultContainerName = "enerteckEntities"
            edsFuelPrices.EnableFlattening = False
            edsFuelPrices.EntitySetName = "dieselprices"
            'edsFuelPrices.Include = "Date,NYMarineDiesel"
            edsFuelPrices.Select = "it.[Date], it[NYMarineDiesel]"
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("An error occurred while loading this page: " & ex.Message.ToString())
        End Try
    Else
        'need to add the code on postbacks, the data returned for the chart is  determined by what checkboxes are checked in the checkboxlist

    End If
                'FormatXAxisLabels(chtFuelPrices, "MainChartArea", 9)
                FormatYAxisLabels(chtFuelPrices, "MainChartArea", 9)
                FormatLineCharts(chtFuelPrices, True, "MainLegend", "Fuel Types")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you missing a dot between 'it' and the property name? - you have `it[NYMarineDiesel]` and I believe you should have `it.[NYMarineDiesel]"`